# How to iterate over a string and find out if it is available in an object literal?

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, literals, hasownproperty

```
var leet = {
    h: 1,
    e: 2,
    r: 3,
    o: 4,
    l: 5
};

var s = "hello";
var fin = "";

for (var i in s) {
    if (leet.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        fin + = leet[i];
    } else {
        fin + = i
    }
}
console.log(fin);
```

Why am I getting an error?

Comment: syntax for concatenation is incorrect. it should be `+=` without space.

Comment: What's your error....??

Comment: Don't use a `for in` loop to iterate over a string. Use `for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {` and use `s.charAt(i)` to get the letter.

Comment: Depending on what you actually want in the output, here's something that's working: http://jsfiddle.net/W9gbJ/

Comment: @FaisalSayed  Oops No, its not fixed, My output should be 12554. and its 01234

Comment: @user1223844 Check my answer and fiddle please

Comment: @user1223844 you already got the answer .. Output for my code is 12554 .. What can i do if you don't check it properly...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your i value is 0,1,2,3,4 .. To get the char , you should use s[i] and string concat is += not + =

I mean

```
for (var i in s)
{
   alert(i);   // Gives 0,1,2,3,4
   alert(s[i]);  // Gives h,e,l,l,o
}
```

The below code  gives you the expected result

```
var leet = {
        h: 1,
        e: 2,
        r: 3,
        o: 4,
        l: 5
    };

var s = "hello";
var fin = "";

for (var i in s) {
    if (leet.hasOwnProperty(s[i])) {
        fin += leet[s[i]];
    } else {
        fin += i
    }
}
alert(fin);
```

[Working JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HCcC3/)

Comment: Click the link man and see the output.. Don't you have eyes ...?? Output for this code is 12554 .. Click http://jsfiddle.net/HCcC3/

Comment: Great! Thats it! Thank you

Comment: @user1223844 same .. Me too don't know the reason for downvote.. Even now , you can accept it..

Comment: @user1223844 Click the TICK symbol on the left side of my answer

Comment: I did not downvote, but the reason someone probably did is because of this popular thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea ... In this case, I see no potential for error with its use, but if you choose to use this technique in a more complicated example, you could run into problems.  Although you are only executing code on "has Own" properties, it's still looping over each property/method all the way up the prototype chain. A regular for(1 = 0; i < s.length; i++) loop is going to be more efficient & prevents potential errors.

Comment: @mikeyUX answering or pointing the drawback in an answer is good .. Good of you but why to downvote without saying reason ...?? And you know one user is giving downvote for all my answers now .. Just check my profile .. Don't know who that coward is ...!!!

Comment: @PrasathK Please read my comment again - i said i DID NOT downvote, but that drawback MAY be the reason why someone else did.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation operator for object `String` is `+=` not `+ =`

For getting `fin` get value according to contents in `s` ypur code should be like this

```
for (var i in s) {
    if (leet.hasOwnProperty(s[i])) {
        fin += leet[s[i]];
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yup that definitely helped!

Answer (score 0):

edit as **fin += leet[i]** and **fin += i** by removing the space within then now you can get your result as **"01234"**